# Is Dataprotectionprovider fips compliant in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin

generating cookies like this in .net core

```
    // Now we create a data protector, with a fixed purpose and sub-purpose used in key derivation.
    var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(keyRingPath));
    var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector(
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
        "Cookie",
        "v2");
    // And finally create a new auth ticket formatter using the data protector.
    var ticketFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);

    //// Now configure the cookie options to have the same cookie name, and use
    //// the common format.
    //services.AddDataProtection()
    //    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keyRingPath)).SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp"); ;
    services.AddAuthentication(CookiesPolicy.AuthenticationType).AddCookie(CookiesPolicy.AuthenticationType,options =>
    {
        options.TicketDataFormat = ticketFormat;
        options.Cookie.Name = CookiesPolicy.Name;
    });
```

Is this FIPS compliant?

In .net frame work we are using Owin.Security.AesDataProtectorProvider for fips compliant hashing.

```
    //use FIPS-compliant hashing algorithms (2nd param = true)
    var cookieKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieKey"];
    appBuilder.UseAesDataProtectorProvider(cookieKey, true);
```

So basically looking fips compliant encryption in asp.net core

Comment: Basically all .net encryptions rely on the underlying OS itself and that in itself isn't necessarily FIPS compliant. So all the managed cryptographic algorithm implementations (e.g. AesManaged) in the .NET Framework are not certified.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I see this [owin.security.aesdataprotectorprovider](https://github.com/i4004/Owin.Security.AesDataProtectorProvider/blob/master/Owin.Security.AesDataProtectorProvider/CrypticProviders/AesCspFactory.cs) differentiating fips in terms of managed implementation vs may be call forwarding implementation. So I guess .net core implementation is fips compliant in that sense?

Comment: Enabling FipsAlgorithmPolicy on windows should make a system fips compliant in .net core?

Comment: Yes i was about to say that has to be enabled. Also not all are compliant even when enabling it.

Comment: Also, yes, what you are doing actually delegates to AesCryptoServiceProvider under the hood which in fact is compliant. So I amend my first comment. By passing `true` as the second arg, you're doing the right thing; its telling it to be compliant.

Comment: Thanks. But that is in .net full framework. how can I  achieve that in asp .net core?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201897/discussion-between-sameer-and-codx).